# How to use class variable from pyqt5 script in another python file

Tags: python, object, oop, pyqt, pyqt5

I have a simple pyqt5 script that makes the following UI:
[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqSwh.png)

The python file for this code is named 'Test.py' and is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 400)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 90, 91, 31))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(240, 100, 113, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 150, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.function)       #<<<<<<<< MY INPUT

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Form", "Job Number"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "Press it"))

    def function(self):                                   #<<<<<<<< MY INPUT
        self.text = self.lineEdit.text()                   #<<<<<<<< MY INPUT
        return self.text                                    #<<<<<<<< MY INPUT


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I simply want to use the 'self.text' value that is generated on a different python file called 'Test1.py'.

I tried tried the following in the 'Test1.py' file:

```
from Test import Ui_Form

obj = Ui_Form()
obj.function()
```

But I keep getting the following error:
AttributeError: 'Ui_Form' object has no attribute 'lineEdit'

Comment: `self.lineEdit` is created by calling the `setupUi()` method.  So call `obj.setupUi()` first, before calling `obj.function()`.

Comment: lineEdit and text are not class variables, they are object (instance) variables